# How to force nodejs socket.io client use TLSv1.2?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tls1.2, tls1.3

I have a nodejs socket.io client that uses TLSv1.3 by default when trying to connect to the server. I want to disable TLSv1.3 (or force the client to use TLSv1.2 specifically).
The client snippet for connection:

```
const socket = io.connect("wss://test.mydomain.com", {
    path: "/persistent-connection",
    transports: ["websocket", "polling"]
});
```

I have searched through the socket.io documentation but could not find something like setting `secureProtocol:"TLSv1_2_method"` in the client options.
Any idea as to how this can be achieved? Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Nodejs 10.x or above you can use `NODE_OPTIONS=--tls-max-v1.2` CLI option to configure TLS version or in code you can do as below:

```
const tls = require('tls');

tls.DEFAULT_MAX_VERSION = 'TLSv1.2';
```